# FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I moved the `NavigationTabbedActivity` from one project to another, but I'm getting this error:

> `setSupportActionBar` method cannot be found.

I've tried replacing the `import widget.toolbar` with `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Actually it needs the class to extend `Activity` but in my case the class already extends `CustomActivity` which in turn extends the default `AndroidActivity`, I tried extending `customActivity` with `AppCombatActivity` but it didn't work either. Is this error because I copied the file? Where am i wrong?

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar); Ok im getting Error in this line as  cannot resolve method  setSupportActionBar  in  android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok while copying the file i forgot to add appcompat in the manifest file.  so add the  AppCompatActivity in the manifest file  ie)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
```

and extended the custom activity to AppCompatActivity , and resynced the project , that solved the problem , thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the small amount of information that was given I will try and provide a answer.

- First of, when you copy a file over to a new project the activity doesn't exist in your`Manifest.xml` so make sure you declare it in your manifest.
- You would also have to copy the layout file from the previous project or change it in your new one.
- The next thing is the old project name will still be at the top and needs to be changed to the new project name.

**My best advice** would be to remove all the imports at the top and import everything again to make sure all the classes and everything is imported correctly.